# League History Tracking

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I want to see my best league position of all times. Is that possible? Do we have a history for the league positions? Because I was in top 0.30% of something but I don't remember what. Now I am in top 3% of the week, but I want to check all my league achievements. I don't have a lot for now, but in the future I hope it will be useful to check my history for such a thing.
That didn't solve my question. As I still can't find in which league I was in the top 0.30%

*Marked as duplicate? I think the people that voted for the should be banned, because they are kidding with their priviledges. I think when they see the word league and they mark as duplicate. To these who marked it as duplicate: people please read better these questions, because we the users are wasting time to think think think, then write and its well formed question, its unique question and you are ruining the website and OP passion for writing.*

***A feature where we can see our top rankings in each league would be great!***

Comment: Aside from ranting can you explain why this isn't the same as the linked duplicate? I can't see how you're asking for anything different

Comment: how can you see your best achievement? in all types of leagues

Comment: what is your best achievement ever? there is not a feature to tell you

Comment: Yes and that is exactly what the duplicate is asking for isn't it?